# Golang pq sql driver: get record ids after bulk import

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

Using the pq sql driver for golang, I'm the doing a bulk import as described [in the pq docs](http://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Bulk_imports). Is there a way I can get the ids of the created records?

Comment: The underlying PostgreSQL `COPY` command does not provide a way to return a resultset for generated columns. So no, there isn't, except for querying the table to match the inserted data and looking up any generated keys.

Comment: @CraigRinger Yes, but as it is possible from a Postgres standpoint (using `INSERT INTO ... RETURNING id`), I thought there should be a way for realizing this with the `pq` package.

Comment: Yes, there is ... use `INSERT INTO ... RETURNING`, possibly with a multi-entry `VALUES` list. There is no equivalent for `COPY`, which is what the documentation for your `pq` package's bulk load method suggests it is using. I guess you'd have to write another bulk-load variant function for `pq` that uses batched `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...), (...), (...), ... RETURNING ...` queries instead. Or implement `COPY ... RETURNING ...` :p

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the id column that you are referring to in your COPY statement is based on a serial generation sequence as created by this type of statement:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_serial_name;
```

This means that you can query the current value of the id like this:

```
SELECT currval('my_serial_name');
```

Which will return the current value of the id counter.

As answering any further doubts about this method:

- this statement is **local to the thread and fully isolated**,
- the above statement proves this method to be **useful in a multi user environment and will produce correct value not modified by other insert queries** performed on tables using this sequence

For further reading please refer to urls stating that:

> The sequence functions, listed in Table 9-42 (currval included),
>   provide simple, multiuser-safe methods for obtaining successive
>   sequence values from sequence objects.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-sequence.html

> Because nextval and setval calls are never rolled back, sequence
>   objects cannot be used if "gapless" assignment of sequence numbers is
>   needed. It is possible to build gapless assignment by using exclusive
>   locking of a table containing a counter; but this solution is much
>   more expensive than sequence objects, especially if many transactions
>   need sequence numbers concurrently.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createsequence.html

> To set the transaction isolation level of a transaction, use the
>   command SET TRANSACTION.
>
> Important: Some PostgreSQL data types and functions have special rules
>   regarding transactional behavior. In particular, changes made to a
>   sequence (and therefore the counter of a column declared using serial)
>   are immediately visible to all other transactions and are not rolled
>   back if the transaction that made the changes aborts. See Section 9.16
>   and Section 8.1.4.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/transaction-iso.html

I hope that this answers your question. Postgresql is a great database and can become a very powerful tool when mastered in details. Good luck! :D